# How to define a map property in a separate XML file (in Spring)?

Tags: spring, code-injection

Suppose a project uses Spring and defines it's beans within XMLs ? And it has some bean that accepts a Map in constructor.

Usually, this map is defined as a property under the bean, and has, under it, entries.

But what if the entry list is huge ? It will bloat the XML big time...

Can it (the map) somehow be defined in it's on XML file and then refferenced by the bean that needs it ? How ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, using the `<util:map>` syntax (see [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util)), e.g.

**beans1.xml**

```
<util:map id="myMap">
    <entry .../>
    <entry .../>
    <entry .../>
    <entry .../>
</util:map>
```

**beans2.xml**

```
<import resource="beans1.xml"/>

<bean id="..." class="...">
   <constructor-arg ref="myMap"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: can i do the same but with annotations and SpEL? (a separate bean class, representing the map, that is annotated to inject it's entries with EL)

Answer (score 4):

skaffman's answer worked for me. However, to setup the XML namespaces, **beans1.xml** should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<util:map id="myMap" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <entry key="myKey" value="myValue" />

</util:map>
```